# Predicting w/ Cosine Similarity

Tags: python

```
@staticmethod
def dot(v1,flower):
    dot_prod = 0
    i = 0
    while i<4:
        dot_prod+=float(v1[i])*float(flower[i])
        i+=1
    return dot_prod
@staticmethod
def norm(vec):
    return math.sqrt(iris.dot(vec,vec))

@staticmethod
def sim_score(v1,v2):
    score = iris.dot(v1,v2) / (iris.norm(v1)*iris.norm(v2))
    return score
```

so the point of this program to compare a set of list of lists with input data. Within the lists, there are four float numbers and a type of flower. What i'm merely trying to do is compare each of the flowers with the input the user gives. Would this be a correct way of comparing the input file data and data from a file? flower would be the information from the file

Comment: What is your question? What is flower ?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question in your question.

Comment: Also, for this sort of code I'd highly recommend taking a look at NumPy.

Comment: Im trying to compare data from a file to user input and finding the iris with the highest cosine similarity score

Answer (score 0):

As one commenter mentioned, you should definitely have a look at numpy and scipy, which make a lot of math operations -- particularly those involving matrices and vectors -- much easier.

Cosine distance is directly [available in scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cosine), and would simplify your code considerably:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
score = cosine(v1, v2)
```

Loading data stored in a file depends on the file format. One common way of storing data is in a csv file, where each line contains a single entry (in your case, a flower) with values separated by commas. If you had a file called `flowers.csv` you could load it into a numpy array like this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

# open the csv file to read the data
with open('flowers.csv') as flower_file:

    # create a reader that will read the file line by line
    # and split each line at the commas while reading
    flower_reader = csv.reader(flower_file)

    # map list of string values in each line to floats, 
    # and package the whole thing in a numpy array
    flower_data = np.array([map(float, line) for line in flower_reader])
```

Then if a user provides an input we'll call `user_flower`, we can get the cosine distance between it and each of the flowers in `flower_data` using the scipy function `cosine` as described above:

```
distances = [cosine(user_flower, f) for f in flower_data]
```

The most similar flower will have the smallest number.